# Stuck after logging warning, how to force continuation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, warnings

I have a Python script that loops through a dataframe of tuples to perform certain manipulation. I have used the logging module to issue a warning when it encounters missing data. By default, it should issue the warning and then continue, but it's stuck there. Is there a way to force it to continue after logging the warning?

```
if ctype == 'color': 
    if id not in data.columns:
        logger.warn("Data unavailable")
        return None, atuple
    data=data * 3
```

I'm encountering an instance where the id is not in `data.columns`, and the code is stuck there without moving to the next row. Is there any way I can force it to move forward?

Comment: Are you trying to `continue` or `return`? Those are two different commands

Comment: What he meant is that the `return` ends the loop because it exits the function this is running inside. You need to use another command, as `pass` i.e.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `return` statement, this will end the function call and pass the result back to where it was called from. A function can only ever `return` values once per call. If you want the function to continue you can either collect up your variables and return them at the end, or use the `yield` keyword which will return a value each time that line is hit.